# Certificate SSL issues

Tags: security, ssl, browser, https, certificate

I'm studying web security and I have the following questions:

1. Java (and other language) applications and browsers use CA Certificate to verify certificates.
   But I guess CA Certificate has an expiration date for security reasons. So what happens when CA Certificate expires? I can't find solution expecially for not web contexts.
2. Client side certificates (when present) are signed and provided by the related server??
3. CA Certificate is self-signed. This means that no one can manipulate it.
   But if another person creates another self-signed certificate with the same   common name of CA Certificate? How is it possible to distinguish the real one?
4. I understand that a certificate chain is when a certificate Z is signed by the private key of another certificate X which is itself signe by another private key/certificate and so on until a ROOT certificate.
   My question is: how can browsers check validity of the certificate Z? The server passes just the certificate Z and I don't understand how the brosers finds the other chain certificates.
   I think also that it's not secure the chain certificate how i get it.
5. Why does browsers save certificates of visited servers?
   I have many certificates stored in both firefox and chrome ,for example 
   google one. It's just weird that chrome indicates google certificate as
   untrusted. What part of the certificate checking alghorithm they make 
   quicker saving certificates?

Comment: Could you please provide more context for question 5?  To what specific browser behaviour are you referring?  Browsers do not automatically save end-entity certificates.

Comment: Are the saved certificates in Question 5 CA certificates or server (*end-entity*) certificates?

Comment: I talked about end entity certificate

Answer (score 1):

1. When a CA certificate expires, validation of certificates signed by the expired CA will fail - even if the signed certificate has not expired.  A CA certificate can be renewed by acquiring a new certificate bearing the same *public key* (for the same private key) and *subject distinguished name*, and a later expiry date.

   Because root certificate typically have a very long validity period, a certificate can be renewed with the validity period overlapping the old certificate.  The new certificate can be distributed to clients via browser or OS updates and as long as the *current time* is within its validity period, it can be used to verify signatures.
2. Client certificates and server certificates can be signed by unrelated CAs.  Server configuration will include indicating which CA certificates are trusted for validation of client certificates.
3. It is not the *common name* that matters here, but the *subject distinguished name*, of which common name (CN) is one possible component.  (SDNs with only a CN are common though, especially for websites).

   If two self-signed certificates have the same SDN *and public key*, they are roughly equivalent (modulo validity period, extensions, etc).  Any certificate signed by one can be validated by the other, and vice versa.  But without the *private key* corresponding to the public key, noone will be able to make a signature.  Since noone can generate the same private key as you, and assuming you have kept your private key private, noone besides you can make a useful CA certificate.

   Someone *could* make a CA certificate with the same SDN but different key.  In this case, signatures made by one would not be verifiable by the other, and vice versa.  The certificates would be clearly distinguishable by way of different public key and different information in the *Subject Key Identifier* X.509 extension, which contains a *cryptographic digest* or *hash* of the public key.
4. Servers must pass not just the *end-entity* certificate but any *intermediate certificates*, up to (but usually not including) a root certificate.  Server software will allow you to configure the entire certificate chain to be sent to clients as part of the TLS handshake.  Upon receiving it, clients reassemble and verify the chain, starting from the root certificate which is identified by the *Subject Key Identifier* extension in the first (i.e. topmost) certificate in the chain.

   Whether a certificate is a valid CA (either root or intermediary) depends on a few attributes, the most important of which are the `cA` boolean in the *Basic Constraints* extension, and the `keyCertSign` bit in the *Extended Key Usage* extension.  These are checked when verifying a certificate chain to make sure that each *signing* certificate is a CA certificate.  Public CAs will not issue CA certificates to the general public, so someone cannot easily acquire a certificate that can be used as a valid intermediatary to certify google.com, for example.
5. Browsers typically do not (certainly Firefox does not) automatically save server certificates of visited servers, but some browsers (including Firefox) cache intermediate certificates.  [This blog post](https://blogs.gnome.org/mcatanzaro/2015/01/30/mozilla-is-responsible-for-the-redhat-corpmerchandise-com-fiasco/) covers this practice in detail.

Comment: 1)
if the renewed CA certificate mantains the same public key, I think it maintains the same private key.
But isn't expiration date useful right to avoid to mantain the same couple of key for too long time? because with much time attacker could be find out the private key?
And anyway how can CA spread as soon as possible its new certificate to all (browsers,applications etc)?
Because without the new CA certificate they cannot validate no certificate.
Also the problem is that all servers will be untrusted until they get new certificate sign with new CA certificate.

Comment: 3)In case of a  fake Ca certificate with the same SDN but with different public (and private key). if you know already which is the real CA Certificate public key, ok no problem, but if you don't how you can get the real one?

Comment: 4)
I dont' understand yet why this process is secure  
Because If i pay for a certificate to CA. And with my new certificate I sign a third certificate where Common name and all other information say "I'm google".
The third certificate is fake(because it's not google) but it is still valid because the certificate chain ends up with CA certificate.

Comment: 1) updated answer ; 3) see updated answer for Q4 ; 4) see updated answer ; 5) This is not the behaviour of Firefox.  I can't speak to Chrome.  I think it is strange to have lots of end-entity server certificates in your browser unless you installed them or they were untrusted certificates that were saved as exceptions (thus becoming explicitly trusted server certs)

Comment: 1)But during new Ca certificate is spread, nothing about certificate will work. This appears to me incredible.
Also I think the new CA certificate will have different private key respect the old one. So all sercer-certificate are no valid for the new CA certificate. So all web-servers should ask a new certificate and meanwhile all the web should not work.Again this appears to me incredible.

Comment: 3)So you confirm that you should already know the right public key (and therefore the hash) in order to understand which certificate is the real one.
Without knowing that, it's impossible to get the real one.

Comment: 4)Ok , so normal server certificates can't produce other certificates, right?
Maybe it's possible to produce a server certificate by a normal server certificate but it is not trusted for browsers.

Comment: @Luca it's theoretically possible, but yes, browser validation of the chain will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I'm studying web security and I have the following questions:

> 1. ... what happens when CA Certificate expires? I can't find solution expecially for not web contexts.

(a) They reissue it and (b) all certificates signed by it become invalid. Note that CA certificates have very long expiration periods and the certificates they sign expire much sooner. A CA will provide you with their certificate chain when they sign your certificate. It's up to you to install that chain wherever it should be installed. Java comes with a pre-built truststore containing recognized CA certificates, which is updated with every release of Java.

> 2. Client side certificates (when present) are signed and provided by the related server??

No, they are provided by the client and signed by the client's chosen CA. The server has nothing to do with it. The same client certificate can be used to authenticate itself to any SSL server.

> 3. CA Certificate is self-signed. This means that no one can manipulate it.
>      But if another person creates another self-signed certificate with the same   common name of CA Certificate? How is it possible to distinguish the real one?

A certificate also contains a public key which is implicitly related to a private key. A forger doesn't have access to the CA's private key and is therefore unable to sign anything validly as the CA.

> 4. I understand that a certificate chain is when a certificate Z is signed by the private key of another certificate X which is itself signe by another private key/certificate and so on until a ROOT certificate.
>      My question is: how can browsers check validity of the certificate Z?

It's installed in a set of trusted CA certificates.

> The server passes just the certificate Z and I don't understand how the browsers finds the other chain certificates.

No, the server passes the entire certificate chain.

> I think also that it's not secure the chain certificate how i get it.

Why?

Comment: 1)If certificate are no longer valid when their Root certificate expires even if their expiration date is ok, then
   I don't understand why CA Certificate for example gives expiration dates besides the own expiration
   date.

Comment: How can CA spread as soon as possible its new certificate to all (browsers,applications etc)?
Because without the new CA certificate they cannot validate no certificate.
Also the problem is that all servers will be untrusted until they get new certificate sign with new CA certificate.

Comment: Also for example all applications will not work until the application administrator gets the new CA certificate and for example he modifies the java pre-built truststore with the new CA certificate.
 
 Also I don't see any sense to  pay for a certificate when the CA certificate is near the expiration date, because when  certificate expires even my certificate becomes invalid.

Comment: 3)
Ok, you are right, but if a fake CA certificate signs something, how can a third entity understand which is the right public key to use to decrypt sign?
In other words , a browser has to certificate pretend to be CA one(so same SDN).
And the browser has one certificate to check(decrypt its sign with the CA certificate public key).
How can the browser understand it?
My explanation is that browser are built with the correct one and once you know which is the correct one there are no problem.

Comment: 4)I think it's not secure  because If i pay for a certificate to CA. And with my new certificate I sign a third certificate where Common name and all other information say "I'm google".
The third certificate is fake(because it's not google) but it is still valid because the certificate chain ends up with CA certificate.